# How can I get each combination of a set of arrays in python

Tags: python, python-itertools

How can I (efficiently) get each combination of a group of 1D-arrays into a 2D array?
Let's say I have arrays `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` and I want to create a 2D array with each combination such that I would have 2D arrays that represent `AB`, `AC`, `AD`, `ABC`, `ABD`, ..., `CD`.

For clarity on my notation above:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
B = np.array([2,3,4,5,6])
C = np.array([3,4,5,6,7])
```

so

```
AB = np.array([1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,6])
ABC = np.array([1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6,7])
```

So far I have tried something like:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
B = np.array([2,3,4,5,6])
C = np.array([3,4,5,6,7])
D = np.array([4,5,6,7,8])

stacked = np.vstack((A,B,C,D), axis=0)
combos = []
it2 = itertools.combinations(range(4), r=2)
for i in list(it2):
    combos.append(i)
it3 = itertools.combinations(range(4), r=3)
for i in list(it3):
    combos.append(i)
it4 = itertools.combinations(range(4), r=4)
for i in list(it4):
    combos.append(i)
```

which gets me a list of all the possible combos.  then I can apply something like:

```
for combo in combos:
    stacked[combo,:]
    #Then I do something with each combo
```

And this is where I get stuck
This is fine when it's only `A,B,C,D` but if I have `A,B,C,... X,Y,Z` then the approach above doesn't scale as I'd have to call itertools 20+ times.
How can I overcome this and make it more flexible (in practice the number of arrays will likely be 5-10)?

Comment: `for r in range(1:21): #etc.`? The code that you have seems to be manually looping over `r` -- just make it a proper loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have also recommended, use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
import numpy as np

from itertools import combinations

A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
B = np.array([2,3,4,5,6])
C = np.array([3,4,5,6,7])

arrays = [A, B, C]

combos = []
for i in range(2, len(arrays) + 1):
    combos.extend(combinations(arrays, i))

for combo in combos:
    arr = np.vstack(combo)  # do stuff with array
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an additional outer for-loop:

```py
arrays = np.array([  # let's say your input arrays are stored as one 2d array
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    ...
])

combos = []
for r in range(2, len(arrays)+1):
    combos.extend(it.combinations(range(len(arrays)), r=r))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have N items, there are 2^N combinations, so this will take 2^N iterations.

You can go through these 2^N iterations with a single loop if you use a for loop for the range 0 <= n < (2^N) and use bitwise operations to select the items from the list of items according the the current n.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
from itertools import combinations

A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
B = np.array([2,3,4,5,6])
C = np.array([3,4,5,6,7])

lst = [A,B,C]
[list(combinations(lst, i)) for i in range(1,len(lst)+1)]
```

out:

```
# [[(array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),),
#   (array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),),
#   (array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7]),)],
#  [(array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])),
#   (array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])),
#   (array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7]))],
#  [(array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7]))]]
```